# Cannot connect to local mdf database C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, mdf

I have a Database file added to my solution:

[image: Error ScreenShot]

But when I try to add a connection I get the above error:

Different error when using localhost:

[image: localhost error]

Error when using '.' as server name

[image: . error]

I have added the entity framework to the solution via Nuget and have the following installed:

[image: Installed SQL Screenshot]

And Sql express does seem to be running as well.

[image]

Any Ideas on why I'm getting this error or how to solve it?

Comment: if you type in `localhost` for the server name and try to connect, does that work?

Comment: As the error suggests, you should check your Windows Application event log. What does it say?

Comment: @drew_w made got a different error, see above screenshot

Comment: @KyleHale where do i find the event log?

Comment: @BrianPeach Try it without the `\v11.0`. What happens then?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @CodeSlinger I'm trying to Create An Entity Framework Database First Model, but first i need to do this then i can select the fields to map

Comment: Are you trying to add a database to a local instance or embed a database in your project?

Comment: Event Log: Open your Start menu, search for "Event", select "Event Viewer" from the results. Then Windows Logs -> Application.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've forgotten the slash in your server name.

You have `(localdb)v11.0`. Please try `(localdb)\v11.0` instead.

Comment: Tried your fix, got the same error (updated above screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Try using just "." (without quotes) as server name. This should represent your local sqlexpress instance

**EDIT:**

I believe that you need to import your MDF into your local SQL Instance rather then add this to your project. If you wanted to create an embedded Database the file extension would be SDF not MDF.

you can do this by adding the mdf file to the folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

and then attach the database inside of SQL Management Studio

[image]

Or use SQL Import

Answer (score 0):

Basically the standard connection string for sql server is:

```
Server=<ADDRESS>\<INSTANCE>;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE>;User ID=<USER>;Password=<PASS>;
```

So, if you look at this, the issue you are having right now is with the `address\instance` part of this. The default settings here are for the server address to be "localhost" and for the instance name to be either "sqlexpress" or just blank (no instance name, which means you don't need the slash after the server address). If you aren't sure how you installed this you can find your instance name by following these instructions: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb7ce542-be81-436a-bcd0-e6590f7ea003/instance-names-of-the-sql-server-?forum=sqlkjmanageability.

Best of luck!